# Write each element of a vector in file separated by tab - R

Tags: r

I need to prepare a file for a tool I am using.
The file should have the structure

```
Mutant
Mutant:A
Expression
Gene_A:0.5 Gene_B:1 Gene_C:3
Weight: 5
```

I wrote the following function to create such a file, where the value for the mutant and weight are used as inputs in the function, while the expression values (ie. Gene_A: 0.5 ... Gene_C:3) are taken from a vector. In the final file, I need the expression values to be separated by `\t`.

```
prep_file <- function(mutant, expression, weight, file_name){
  sink(paste0(file_name))
  cat("Mutant\n")
  cat(mutant,"\n")
  cat("Expression\n")
  cat(expression)
  cat("\n")
  cat("Weight:",weight)
  sink()
}
```

That can be used as such:

```
expres_vec <- c("Gene_A:0.5","Gene_B:1","Gene_C:3")
prep_file("Mutant:A",expres_vec,"5","test")
```

To create the test file in the example above.

How can I replace the `cat(expression)` in order to write each element of the `expres_vec` separated by a tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `paste` with the `collapse` option. For example:

```
cat(paste(expres_vec, collpase = "\t"))
```

Where `"\t"` designates a tab (you can you any other character or regular expression here if needed).

Or in your function:

```
prep_file <- function(mutant, expression, weight, file_name){
  sink(paste0(file_name))
  cat("Mutant\n")
  cat(mutant,"\n")
  cat("Expression\n")
  cat(paste(expression, collpase = "\t"))
  cat("\n")
  cat("Weight:",weight)
  sink()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `list` the arguments and name them with the `formalArgs` of the function, helpful especially if the output might get more lines i.e. arguments, in the future.

```
prep_file <- function(Mutant, Expression, Weight, file_name) {
  l <- list(mutant, expression, weight) |> setNames(paste0(formalArgs(prep_file)[1:3], ':'))
  invisible(Map(cat, lapply(names(l), paste0, '\n'), lapply(l, paste0, '\t'), '\n')) |>
    capture.output(file=file_name)
}

prep_file("Mutant:A", expres_vec, 5, "test")
# Mutant:
#   Mutant:A     
# Expression:
#   Gene_A:0.5   Gene_B:1    Gene_C:3    
# Weight:
#   5
```

Not sure, where the indentation comes from, but actually it improves readability :)